# Android app crash with error 'com.facebook.jni.CppException : Can't find variable: setTimeout' android 64 bit APK with React native 0.59.10

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

App crashing on launch with setTimeOut error

I have created project using create-react-native-web command & upgraded 0.55.x to 0.59.10 for android 64 bit support using https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.55.3&to=0.59.10

We are facing below error on launching app crash -

Error in details -

```
com.facebook.jni.CppException: Can't find variable: setTimeout

index.android.bundle:206:7357
h@index.android.bundle:2:1670
index.android.bundle:205:53
h@index.android.bundle:2:1670
index.android.bundle:204:92
h@index.android.bundle:2:1670
index.android.bundle:13:2046
h@index.android.bundle:2:1670
index.android.bundle:11:46
h@index.android.bundle:2:1670
d@index.android.bundle:2:868
global code@index.android.bundle:304:4
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:2
```